# Apply regex to .txt file node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to escape quotes in txt file using **node.js** and **regex**.
My code looks like this:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const utf8 = require("utf8");

var dirname = ".\\f\\";
const regex = new RegExp(`(?<=".*)"(?=.*"$)`, "gm");
fs.readFile(dirname + "test.txt", (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  var d = data.toString();
  d = utf8.encode(d)
  console.log(`File: ${typeof d}`); //string
//  d = `Another string\n"Test "here"."\n"Another "here"."\n"And last one here."`;
  console.log(`Text: ${typeof d}`); //string
  var re = d.replace(regex, '\\"');
  console.log(`Result:\n${re}`);
/* Another string
"Test \"here\"."
"Another \"here\"."
"And last one here."
*/
});
```

**The problem is:**

When I remove comment from the line, everything works fine. But if i read the text from the file it doesn't want to work.

Thanks for any comments on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. turns out the problem was in file encoding. The file was encoded in UTF-16, not in UTF-8. Node.js wasn't giving me any signs of wrong encoding, so well, nice.